# Windows Defender showing Trojan virus in my own created XLSM file

Tags: excel, vba, virus, windows-defender, jsonconverter

I'm getting notifications from Windows Defender on my laptop (HP, Windows 10) that the file i myself created, has `Trojan:Win32/Leonem` & `Trojan:O97M/Sadoca.C!ml` viruses. Here's a screenshot of the threat warning I received today:

[image]

I am the creator of the Excel macro-enabled file; it has a bunch of in-built windows references being used & an external [JSONConveter module](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas). These references & json module have been in the file for a long time. Before today I didn't receive any sorts of warnings for my xlsm files, all of a sudden "Severe" warnings are popping up for all copies I have of this file. Haven't noticed this virus error so far in any of my users' PCs.

Is there something suddenly wrong with the file, or the `JSONConverter` is the issue here, which is triggering the Trojan flags?

Comment: You can submit files for analysis to Microsoft you think are false positives here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/wdsi/filesubmission

Comment: Besides doing what (correctly) recommended above, try placing the respective workbook in a Trusted location and run it from there.

Comment: Other virus checkers are available.

Comment: Anyhow, if it does not work even placing it in a trusted location folder, you can stop Defender for some time, but take care to not open workbooks received from unknown sources...